# Angular wrapped Iframe-resizer(Get Iframe target site height)

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular5, iframe-resizer

I tried to get the content window height to set the iframe height in angular 5, but iam unable to do that because iam using different domain url in my src tag.
Im getting exception like "blocked because of cors".

**HTML:**

```
 <iframe id="appIframe" src="http://docstation-st1.dvllb.travp.net/DocStation" (load)="resizeIframe($event)"  scrolling="no" frameborder="0"   ></iframe>
```

**HomeComponent.ts**

```
resizeIframe(obj) {
 var height = obj.target.contentDocument.innerheight;
......
   }
```

**Exception:**

Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://OtherDomain/home.html" from accessing a cross-origin frame

**Tried :**

I tried below iframe-resizer but no luck

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/issues/478

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Can someone help me on this issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @mad_fox : Im still trying by using various solutions but still i didnt get proper solution.Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the values of properties from different-origin-iframe, you can do host-to-iframe communication using [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

You have access to the code of different-origin-iframe, then send an event from there and listen to it in your host component.